# What do "finite" and "non-finite" mean in linguistics?

Tags: terminology, verbs, clauses, infinitive

What do "finite" and "non-finite" mean in linguistics? I know that they occur in other languages and in some cases not only in verbs.

Comment: I have never encountered the term _finite_ used in grammar for anything but verb inflection. Never nouns, and always morphological inflection. In English grammar there is a big distinction between finite verbs (present and past tense forms) and non-finite verbs (participles, gerunds, and infinitives). But that's just **English** grammar.

Comment: @jlawler There are definitely grammars of English, well known ones, for example *CaGEL* (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002), or *Oxford Modern English Grammar* which consider finiteness and non-finiteness properties of **clauses** rather than (necessarily) verbs. One reason for this is the presumption that any fully and well-formed sentence must be a finite clause, whereas the verb-forms therein may appear in both finite and non-finite clauses. So, for example, those grammars recognise a single plain form of the verb appearing in both imperatives and subjunctives (finite), and also 'bare infinitives'.

Comment: @jlawler Where the latter are definitely non-finite.

Comment: OK, I'd go with that; like transitivity, a clausal property. Just not finite nouns.

Comment: While "finite" isn't used for nouns, it's possible you're getting confused by "definite" which is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In traditional grammar a finite form of a verb is a fully specified verb form according to all verbal categories relevant to the specific language, like voice, aspect, mood, tense, person, or number.

Non-finite verb forms are underspecified in this respect, leaving out some of the categories required for a finite verb form (typically tense, person and number). Examples of non-finite verb form include infinitives, gerunds, participles, or the Latin gerundive. Languages vary in the number of non-finite verb forms they have, and there are languages not having them at all.

Comment: I never knew that. What is a language that has no non-finite forms?

Comment: The first paragraph seems a little too strict here – a finite form is specified according to _those categories that exist in the language_ out of voice, aspect, etc. There are many languages whose finite forms do not specify aspect or person, for example. @Araucaria From memory, I don’t think Greenlandic (and hence presumably also other Inuit languages) has non-finite verb forms. It has a ‘participial’ form, but that’s actually a finite form used in subordination.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Should I take that to mean that Greenlandic has verb forms that are used in both finite and non-finite clauses (like, arguably, some English verb forms)?

Comment: @Araucaria-hehim No, I think rather it has no non-finite clauses, only finite ones. But my days of studying Greenlandic are fifteen years behind me, so I may be misremembering something.

Comment: @Araucaria Back home now, I just checked in Michael Fortescue’s grammar of West Greenlandic, which proves me wrong: the nominalising suffix _-niq_ converts a finite verbal clause of any complexity to a noun phrase to be assigned case, possession, etc., and used in subject/object/other-nominal position. In doing so, the marking of mood, person and number is removed from the verbal form, so Greenlandic does have one non-finite form, though as far as I can tell, just the one.

Comment: Another answer with very good comments ... I will make a question out of this: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/46570/9781